# Filter questions with specific tag literally (excluding synonyms)

Tags: support, tags

Is it possible to filter questions on Ask Different (or any Stack Exchange site) with a specific tag **literally** excluding the synonyms?

E.g. I am trying to list all the questions with tag [sed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sed), but the list returned contains all the questions tagged with [unix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix), of which [sed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sed) is a synonym.

The count of questions tagged with [unix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix) is pretty high, and it will be time consuming to sift through them to locate the questions matching the tag [sed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sed) literally.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is not possible because upon synonimizing, all instances of [sed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sed) get *replaced* by [unix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix). This includes post history data in SEDE.

The closest you might be able to get is a [search for `[unix] sed is:q`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bunix%5D+sed+is%3Aq). But I'm not sure how you'd be able to check which questions were originally tagged [sed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sed) and which not.